# Laravel Echo error handling (with Pusher)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher, laravel-echo

Is there any guide about this topic? I have read the [pusher documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#connection-states) and it seems fairly easy to manage a disconnect with a code similar to the following:

```
pusher.connection.bind('disconnected', function() {
    // Do Something
})
```

I'm not sure how to integrate it with Echo, since my code is as follows:

```
window.EchoConnection = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: window.EchoKey,
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});
```

EDIT: in order to check a disconnect event, run `window.EchoConnection.connector.pusher.connection.disconnect()` in your console

Comment: this issue remains open https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/90

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but according to the github repo this should work for pusher:

`window.EchoConnection` is an [Echo](https://github.com/laravel/echo/blob/master/src/echo.ts) Object. When you create a new pusher instance with echo, the `connector` variable will be a [PusherConnector](https://github.com/laravel/echo/blob/master/src/connector/pusher-connector.ts):

```
if (this.options.broadcaster == 'pusher') {
   this.connector = new PusherConnector(this.options);
}
```

Over this variable you can find the Pusher instance that is created:

```
connect(): void {
    this.pusher = new Pusher(this.options.key, this.options);
}
```

The theoretical solution for binding events to the pusher would be:

```
window.EchoConnection.connector.pusher.connection.bind('disconnected', function() {
    // Do Something
})
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! you almost did it... the last bit of code has to be `pusher.connection.bind` instead of `pusher.bind`... fix it for the bounty ;)